# regex: replacing curly brackets with [^ ] around a character

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I am  new to Python
I was trying to modify a string in such a way that the sequence {.} is replaced with [^.] where the dot can represent any character.

I tried writing:

```
 def preprocess_mot (motif):
    motif= re.sub( '\{.*?\}',  lambda m: '[^' + m.group()+"]" ,    motif)  
    print(motif)
```

but it doesn't remove the  curly brackets.

For example

`preprocess_mot("asdasd{d}")`

gives

```
asdasd[^{d}]
```

when it should give

```
asdasd[^d]
```

Comment: Your `'\{.*?\}'` should probably be `r'\{.*?\}'` if you want the backslashes to make it to the regex engine.

Comment: i tried,it still doesn't remove those curly brackets

Comment: @khelwood i have added an example, can the question be unlocked now? what's the problem?

Comment: Maybe. It needs several votes to reopen.

Comment: Use a capture group: `motif= re.sub( '\{(.*?)\}',  lambda m: '[^' + m.group(1) + "]" ,  motif)`

Comment: @Toto wow thanks, damn i was so close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make my comment an answer:

Use a capture group:

```
motif= re.sub( '\{(.*?)\}', lambda m: '[^' + m.group(1) + "]" , motif)  
#                 ^___^                            __^
```